# How to handle image click under Button click event

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi all i am having 2 imagebuttons a gridview and a button. Now if i clicked on Image button i will show a grid. Now under button click i would like to capture which image button was clicked if 1st image button is clicked i would like to some values and if 2nd one is clicked i would like to show another

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can discern which button was pressed by comparing the `sender` parameter:

```
void MyButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    if (sender == MyButton1)
    {
        // 1st image button was clicked — some values
    }
    else if (sender == MyButton2)
    {
        // 2nd one was clicked — show another
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you create 2 events and one function?
ex:

```
//Hook both OnClick events to these!    
private void OnButton1Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { BeenClicked(button1); }
private void OnButton2Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { BeenClicked(button2); }

private void BeenClicked(Button ClickedButton) 
{
    if(ClickedButton.Text == Button1) Console.WriteLine("Hi to you too!"); 
}
```

Or alternatively you could use:

```
//Hook both OnClick events to this!
private void OnButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    ClickedButton = (Button)sender; 
    if(ClickedButton.Text == Button1) Console.WriteLine("Hi to you too!"); 
}
```

If I understood you right :)

Comment: But for Imagebutton text option is not available

Comment: Some what ok but i am unable to handle this in button click

Comment: Why the comparison with `.Text`? Just compare the button itself: `if (sender == MyButton1) ...`

Comment: Sorry had a complete mind lapse, I up voted yours to thank you for pointing out my retarded ways :)